# Is there a way we can integrate Ms outlook compose , Ms teams send message and Viva engage new post in a react application

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams, deep-linking, yammer

I have a react application , I want to deeplink ms outlook compose , ms teams chat feature and viva engage new post feature to the application. Such that when I click on each of these buttons it should open up the respective applications and prefill details provided in react app in the mail, chat or post and allow the user to modify and send

I tried going through Microsoft documentation found a way to deeplink ms outlook webclient compose by proper URL structure https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?subject=SUBJECT&body=BODY&to=user@domain.com
And for teams https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com&topicName=Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow&message=Hi%20folks%2C%20kicking%20off%20a%20chat%20about%20our%20meeting%20tomorrow
I want something similar for viva engage as well

Comment: For Viva Engage, there is currently no specific deep link available to create a new post. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472). Please refer the available document to [Integrate Viva Engage with other Microsoft applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/viva/engage/integrate-viva-engage-with-other-apps/integrate-with-other-applications#viva-engage-and-teams). You can also refer:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/viva/engage/deeplinks